# What's the proper way of importing option lists into an Android app?

Tags: android, xml, translation

I have been storing option lists for my Android app in a cloud table. For example, categories like "historical fiction","biography","science fiction", etc.  I see the following pros and cons:

Pro:

- I can make changes to the list without sending an app update to Google Play
- Not normalized - I can use the text in my other data tables instead of a reference ID

Con:

- App needs to take time to download from the web each time (or at least check for changes)
- English only

I believe the "proper" way to do this is the use the XML resource files.  But I need to make sure the selection references correctly with my data.  That is, my app needs to understand that "Poetry" and "Poesía" are the same thing.

Is the correct thing to do:

1. Forget about it since I'll never get to the point where I'm translating my app anyway
2. Use a string-array and use the index (0...x) to know what the selection is
3. Use a 2-dimensional string-array with a reference ID in the first column and the text in the second?

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the category list online, then why not handle the translations online as well. Here is what I would suggest:

In your application options, have a list of supported languages (each in their native translation). These language options should be stored on whatever server application is handling your web requests. Each language is associated with an integer ID that the user does not see, but is stored in the app.

Whenever you issue a web request to get a list of options, include the language id in the message. This will allow you to know what language the user has picked and can use a 2D array or some other structure to handle the conversion to and from the chosen language.

I'm not sure if this helps at all, since I don't know exactly what you are making or how you are designing it, but from the given description, this is an easy and effective course of action.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I don't yet have translations for my app.  I'm trying to do things the "right" way (if there is one).  That's certainly would work, although currently I don't maintain a language_ID - I would have let Android do the heavy lifting automatically.  What if the selected language differs from their device language?

Comment: The point of having the language sourcing online is that you could pull down the language files from your server whenever the language is changed. This would allow you to add languages to the app without having to update through Google Play. Basically, you are ignoring the device language and using your online system to handle translation for the entire app.